# Save images to NSMutableDictionary and than to plist

Tags: ios, image, dictionary, plist

I need to save images which I get from server using

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]]];
```

To NSMutableDictionary - it's ok for me, I'm doing it like this (it is in loop for every fetched image):

```
[self.imagesDict setObject:image forKey:[[xmlArray objectAtIndex:x] objectForKey:@"_img"]];
```

And than, I need to save it to disc. There were two solutions for me, but no one works... :-(. First one was save it do NSUserDefaults and second is save it to .plist file to root of iPhone. I want to go with that .plist, so I did:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pathLD = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imagesDict"];

[self.imagesDict writeToFile:pathLD atomically:YES];
```

But when I try to NSLog it, it's not working. However when I save to dictionary some string instead of image, it works like a charm. So can someone help me please what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "But when I try to NSLog it, it's not working." - *what* is not working? *how?* What does this have to do with Xcode?

Comment: Not working means that it is not logging anything... And xCode because I'm coding in xCode? :-) Sorry for that if it is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not store the `UIImage` objects directly. Put their `NSData` inside the `NSDictionary` to be able to save them. Either the downloaded `NSData` or create it new via `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

From the Dokumentation of `NSDictionary`'s `writeToFile:atomically:`

`This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.`

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems. First, you should really use .plist as the file extension of your dictionary. But more importantly, you're trying to save a dictionary that contains an object (UIImage) that cannot be serialized to a plist. Plists only support a limited number of object types, such as NSNumber, NSData, NSString. Looks at the writeToFile:atomically: description in the NSDictionary class reference. It has a list of what's allowed. If you want to save an image to a plist, you have to serialize it yourself into an NSData. I don't think it's a good idea, though, because the NSData representation might be a lot larger than the original image. I think you would be better off finding another way to do this.

Comment: I have tried to save that to NSData and than save that to plist, but it's not working, NSLog just says "(null)"... :-(